# Using CPD/PMD on the command line

Tags: ide, pmd, cpd

I'm using PMD currently as an external tool in conjunction with ace editor on an online java IDE i'm developing. However I can't get the CPD batch file to work, I've tried the command they provide on the website documentation as well as a few alternatives. 
Could someone please give me the required command if i want to search for duplicate code?
here is my cpd directory and project source.
C:\Users\Neema\Desktop\pmd-bin-5.2.2\bin
C:\Users\Neema\workspace\Gillespie\src
I know this is simple, but if anyone could help it would bee GREATLY appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: editor and ace-editor tags seems to be wrong, since question is not about ace

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using PMD as an external tool to analyse code on Ace

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to start cpd with this command line:

```
C:\Users\Neema\Desktop\pmd-bin-5.2.2\bin\cpd --minimum-tokens 100 --files C:\Users\Neema\workspace\Gillespie\src --language java
```

Note, that cpd is a command line tool - if you don't run it from a console (e.g. `cmd`), then you won't see the output. You can try to redirect stdout into a file via this command line:

```
C:\Users\Neema\Desktop\pmd-bin-5.2.2\bin\cpd --minimum-tokens 100 --files C:\Users\Neema\workspace\Gillespie\src --language java > C:\Users\Neema\workspace\Gillespie\src\cpd-results.txt
```

The [CPD documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.3/usage/cpd-usage.html) unfortunately doesn't describe to use the simple `cpd.bat` file in the bin folder (like above)...

Comment: Thank you very much,
adangel, I have another question regarding PMD if you could answer it. 
I'll provide a link to the question now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259910/selecting-specific-rule-sets-in-command-for-pmd-code-analyzer